# Buttons To Add A Row and Add A column Bug?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table as you can see in the image. The add row and add column button when pressed takes a user input meaning if the user wants the column in lets say  C of the table it gets generated; same for the row button.

If I **added a column in C** using the column button and I added **a row at line 5** using the row button look at what occurs:

Notice column C how the colors are distorted??

The only time this does not occur is if the user entered values that created rows and columns at **the end of the table**.

**Add Row button code** :

```
  Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim varUserInput As Variant
Dim inpt As String
Dim oLo As ListObject
Dim RowNum

inpt = MsgBox("Do You Want To Add A Row At The END Of The Table?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Row Choice")              'user input

If inpt = vbNo Then

' add row to table                                                                                                      'runs if condition is user selected no
    varUserInput = InputBox("Enter The Row Number You Want To Generate:", _
  "What Row?")

 If varUserInput = "" Then Exit Sub

    RowNum = varUserInput                                                                                            'adds row based on user input
    Rows(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).Insert shift:=xlDown
    Rows(RowNum - 1 & ":" & RowNum - 1).Copy Range("A" & RowNum)
    Range(RowNum & ":" & RowNum).ClearContents

    Else

            Set oLo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)                                                                         'first table on sheet

            With oLo
            .ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True                                                                            'adds row to end of table
            .Range.Rows(.Range.Rows.Count).RowHeight = 30

            End With
              End If

        End Sub
```

**Add Column button:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()

 ' add column to table
 Dim userinput As String
 Dim QuestionToMessageBox  As String
 Dim colIndex As Variant
 Dim StrtRow As Long, EndRow As Long, i As Long
 Dim oLo As ListObject

  userinput = MsgBox("Do you want to add the column at the END of the table?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Column Choice")   'user input

    If userinput = vbNo Then                                                                                                'condition if no is selected

    On Error GoTo Canceled                                                                          '

    colIndex = Application.InputBox("Enter a column that you want to add: ", "What column?")
    If colIndex = "" Then Exit Sub



    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns(colIndex).Insert shift:=xlRight                                                '<--| reference column you want to insert

        'sheet row numbers from table rows
        Set oLo = .ListObjects(1)                                                                '<~~ first table on sheet
        With oLo
            StrtRow = .ListRows(1).Range.Row
            EndRow = .ListRows.Count + StrtRow - 1
        End With

        For i = StrtRow To EndRow
            .Cells(i, colIndex).Interior.Color = .Cells(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next i
    End With


    Else                                                                                                'condition if yes is selected


    Set oLo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)                                                                 'first table on sheet
    With oLo
    .ListColumns.Add
    .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Range.ColumnWidth = 25



    End With
    'macro loops through to end of table to generate the proper around column lines

    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Stages]]").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Loop
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Activate

     Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    End If
Canceled:
  End Sub
```

Comment: Can you create a shorter example that shows the problem without additional detail?

Comment: Ok I tried to make it shorter but the code is somewhat long, also the example of the problem I don't know how to make it shorter since its the only problem I am having.

Comment: Doug You there? I Don't know how else to make it shorter?

Comment: I'm here. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're dealing with a `ListObject` the formatting should just work, so I removed all the code that was supposed to format the table. I may have missed something and you'll need to add it back.

You had an `On Error Goto Cancelled` statement at the beginning of your column procedure which was basically an `On Error Exit Sub` statement. Unless you were very clear on what errors you expected your code could quit at any error with unexpected or misunderstood results.

Below is my attempt to simplify both routines. I moved things around a lot to try to avoid repetition, got rid of some Variant variables and made other changes.

I also changed the `InputBox` to an `Application.InputBox`, which allows you to specify the input type. This means that a blank response will throw up a confusing message to the user, though, so I put `Application.DisplayAlerts` around the `InputBox` prompt to suppress the message.

I hope this works as is, I expect that something will be off from what you want. Hopefully though it will get you partway there and show you some new tricks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
'add row to table
   Dim InputPosition As Long
   Dim InputEndOfTable As VbMsgBoxResult
   Dim oLo As ListObject

   Set oLo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)                                                                         '
   With oLo
      InputEndOfTable = MsgBox("Do You Want To Add A Row At The END Of The Table?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Row Choice")
      If InputEndOfTable = vbNo Then
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         InputPosition = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter The Row Number You Want To Add:", Title:="What Row?", Type:=1)
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      Else
         InputPosition = .Range.Rows.Count + 1
      End If
      If InputPosition = 0 Then Exit Sub
      If InputEndOfTable = vbYes Then
         .ListRows.Add
      Else
         .ListRows.Add InputPosition
      End If
      .Range.Rows(InputPosition).RowHeight = 30
   End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
'add column to table
   Dim InputPosition As Long
   Dim InputEndOfTable As VbMsgBoxResult
   Dim oLo As ListObject

   Set oLo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)                                                                         '
   With oLo
      InputEndOfTable = MsgBox("Do You Want To Add A Column At The END Of The Table?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add column Choice")
      If InputEndOfTable = vbNo Then
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         InputPosition = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter The Column Number You Want To Add:", Title:="What Column?", Type:=1)
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      Else
         InputPosition = .Range.Columns.Count + 1
      End If
      If InputPosition = 0 Then Exit Sub
      If InputEndOfTable = vbYes Then
         .ListColumns.Add
      Else
         .ListColumns.Add InputPosition
      End If
      .ListColumns(InputPosition).Range.ColumnWidth = 25
   End With
End Sub
```